# Is there something after Hyper Hexagonest?

Tags: super-hexagon

After you have finished the Hyper Hexagonest mode, is there an additional mode unlocked? Or is it just the achievement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have gathered, the final and hardest mode is Hyper Hexgonest. Once you successfully complete this mode, you will get the "Hexagon" achievement (if you already haven't) and are presented with the ending of the game.

So yeah, no more modes unlocked after this currently.

Answer (score 0):

Once you last 60 seconds on Hyper Hexagonest, you enter the seventh mode. Dying during the seventh mode gets you the ending. the seventh mode lasts forever, and cannot be selected. you can only reach it by surviving long enough in hyper hexagonest.